# findtext and xpath not returning anything from my parsed xml document

Tags: python, xml, django, xpath, elementtree

I am using `lxml.etree.parse` in django to parse some content from an external rss feed and using `findall` to workaround the namespace.

I can iterate through the results just find however I am unable to display any text from my results.

Here is what the xml file looks like that I am trying to scrape from:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>Open Library : Author Name</title>
    <link href="http://www.somedomain.org/people/atom/author_name" rel="self"/>
    <updated>2012-03-20T16:41:00Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name>somedomain.org</name>
    </author>
    <id>tag:somedomain.org,2007:/person_feed/123456</id>
    <entry>
        <link href="http://www.somedomain.org/roll_call/show/1234" rel="alternate"/>
        <id>
        tag:somedomain.org,2012-03-20:/roll_call_vote/1234
        </id>
        <updated>2012-03-20T16:41:00Z</updated>
        <title>Once upon a time</title>
        <content type="html">
        This is a book full of words
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Here is what my view in django looks like:

```
def openauthors(request):

    tree = lxml.etree.parse("http://www.somedomain.org/people/atom/author_name")
    namespace = "{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}"
    listings = tree.findall("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")

    listings_info = []

    for listing in listings:
        this_value = {
            "link": listing.findtext("content"),
            "title": listing.findtext("feed/content"),
            "content": listing.findtext("content"),
            }

        listings_info.append(this_value)


    json_listings = '{"listings":' + simplejson.dumps(listings_info) + '}'

    if("callback" in request.GET.keys()):
        callback = request.GET["callback"]
    else:
        callback = None

    if(callback):
        response = HttpResponse("%s(%s)" % (
                callback,
                simplejson.dumps(listings_info)
                ), mimetype="application/json"
            )
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(json_listings, mimetype="application/json")
    return response
```

I have also tried the following using `xpath` in place of `findtext` but am getting the same result.

```
    "link":listing.xpath("link/text()"),
    "title":listing.xpath("entry/link/text()"),
    "content":listing.xpath("content/text()"),
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not take the XML namespace into account.

```py
tree = lxml.etree.parse("http://www.somedomain.org/people/atom/author_name")
xmlns = {"atom": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
listings = tree.xpath("//atom:entry", namespaces=xmlns)

listings_info = []

for listing in listings:
    listings_info.append({
        "link": listing.xpath("./atom:link/@href", namespaces=xmlns),
        "title": listing.xpath("./atom:title", namespaces=xmlns),
        "content": listing.xpath("./atom:content", namespaces=xmlns),
    })
```

You must define a prefix (even if there is none in your XML) and use it in your XPath expressions. This means you have to inform `.xpath()` about what prefix you will use for which namespace, hence the second parameter.

Comment: That mostly seemed to work however I hat to att `/text()` to `"title": listing.xpath("./atom:title", namespaces=xmlns),` to make it `"title": listing.xpath("./atom:title/text()", namespaces=xmlns),` as well as the one for content too. Thanks!

Comment: @bigmike7801 That's right. I was not sure if you needed the elements or their contents.